# center drag and drop proxy on pointer

Tags: javascript, extjs, drag-and-drop, extjs4, extjs4.1

I am using ExtJS drag and drop and trying to center the drag proxy beneath my cursor (proxy: the semi-transparent filler that represents the element being dragged). I can center it physically like this but then it won't drop properly afterwards:

```
view.dragZone = Ext.create('Ext.dd.DragZone', view.getEl(), {

    onStartDrag: function(x, y) {
        this.setDelta(150, 20); // (the element is 300 x 40)
    },

    //.. other DD configs

});
```

When I use this and move the cursor into a drop zone it just slides back to the original position as if I dropped it somewhere random.

If I do not use this the cursor is about 20 pixels NW of the object (i.e. not centered) but I am able to drop it totally fine in a drop zone.

I thought it might have something to with the cursor not being *directly over* the drop zone because it is instead *directly over* the drag proxy now. I tried resetting the z-index of the drop zone to try and bring it *above* the drag proxy but that didn't seem to work. Tried a few other extremely random things that are not worth mentioning.

Has anyone successfully set-up drag and drop so that the drag proxy is centered on the cursor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm able to center the proxy and see it drop properly in the live preview for the [grid drag/drop plugin](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.DragDrop).

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId:'simpsonsStore',
    fields:['name'],
    data: [["Lisa"], ["Bart"], ["Homer"], ["Marge"]],
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: 'array'
    }
});

var p = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    store: 'simpsonsStore',
    columns: [
        {header: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name', flex: true}
    ],
    viewConfig: {
        plugins: {
            ptype: 'gridviewdragdrop',
            dragText: 'Drag and drop to reorganize'
        }
    },
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});

p.view.plugins[0].dragZone.onStartDrag = function() {
    this.setDelta(80, 10);
};
```

`Ext.view.DragZone` doesn't look very different from `Ext.dd.DragZone`. However, `Ext.view.DropZone` adds quite a bit of logic to check where the record is being dropped. I'm guessing that logic is probably why the dropping works correctly for the grid drag/drop plugin.

Comment: After reading through the class, I think you have a point there. Any idea on how to implement it for regular drag/drop?

Comment: What does your DropZone's getTargetByEvent method return as you are dragging? It sounds to me like it's not returning a node. When this happens, the default onContainerOver logic is called which returns false to indicate the drop is not allowed.

Comment: The Ext.view.DropZone's getTargetByEvent method adds additional logic to grab a node based on the mouse's actual position on the page.

Comment: I played around with trying to get the element the mouse is over using a selector of `document.querySelectorAll(':hover')` and also `document.elementFromPoint`, but unfortunately the proxy element is all they return. I guess that means you're stuck with implementing your own version of `getTargetByEvent` that manually grabs the element which has a region in which the current mouse XY position falls. I don't know that it's worth the trouble (and possible efficiency concerns) just to center the mouse cursor over the proxy.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this, you're mostly right. I can also use [css: pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/pointer-events) to great advantage for everything except IE but I have a cross-browser solution working now, I will post an answer in a moment.

Comment: I had to revisit this today... the `this.setDelta` solution still works for 4.2.2. dunno why I never accepted this before